# Split Python Dataframe into multiple Dataframes (where chosen rows are the same)

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I would like to split one DataFrame into N Dataframes based on columns X and Z where they are the same (as eachother by column value).

For example, this input:

```
df = 
   NAME X Y Z Other
0  a    1 1 1 1
1  b    1 1 2 2
2  c    1 2 1 3
3  d    1 2 2 4
4  e    1 1 1 5
5  f    2 1 2 6
6  g    2 2 1 7
7  h    2 2 2 8
8  i    2 1 1 9
9  j    2 1 2 0
```

Would have this output:

```
df_group_0 = 
   NAME X Y Z Other
0  a    1 1 1 1
2  c    1 2 1 3
4  e    1 1 1 5

df_group_1 = 
   NAME X Y Z Other
1  b    1 1 2 2
3  d    1 2 2 4

df_group_2 = 
   NAME X Y Z Other
6  g    2 2 1 7
8  i    2 1 1 9

df_group_3 = 
   NAME X Y Z Other
7  h    2 2 2 8
9  j    2 1 2 0
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupby` generates an iterator of tuples with the first element be the group id, so if you iterate through the groupers and extract the second element from each tuple, you can get a list of data frames each having a unique group:

```
grouper = [g[1] for g in df.groupby(['X', 'Z'])]

grouper[0]
NAME    X   Y   Z   Other
0   a   1   1   1   1
2   c   1   2   1   3
4   e   1   1   1   5

grouper[1]
NAME    X   Y   Z   Other
1   b   1   1   2   2
3   d   1   2   2   4

grouper[2]
NAME    X   Y   Z   Other
6   g   2   2   1   7
8   i   2   1   1   9

grouper[3]
NAME    X   Y   Z   Other
5   f   2   1   2   6
7   h   2   2   2   8
9   j   2   1   2   0
```

Comment: Oh you even caught NAME 5, which I missed. Thank you

Comment: @user2921352 if this answered your question.  Don't forget to mark it as the answer, thx.